# MLE is negative while $\lambda$ should be positive

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

> A probability distribution is given by $$f_X(x) =
>  \frac{e^\frac{-x}{\lambda}x}{\lambda}$$ if $x > 0$ and $f_X(x) = 0$
> otherwise. $\lambda$ is an unknown positive number. Knowingly that for
> a sample of dimension 40, $\sum_{i = 1}^{40} = 142.89$, what is the
> maximum likelihood estimation of $\lambda$?

I did

$$L(\lambda | \underline{x}) = \prod_{I=1}^{n}(\frac{e^\frac{-x}{\lambda}x}{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{\lambda^{2n}}e^{\frac{-1}{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}\prod_{I=1}^{n}(x_i)$$
$$\ln(L(\lambda | \underline{x})) = -2n\ln(\lambda) - \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n\ln(x_i)$$
Now differentiate such that first derivative is zero (to have a stationary point) and such that the second derivative is less than zero (to make sure it is a maximum). And I end up with:

$$\hat{\lambda}: \frac{-2n}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 0, \frac{2n}{\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^3}\sum_{i=1}^n < 0$$

Solving for $\hat{\lambda}$ I get $$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{-2n}$$ which is negative because de sum is positive and $n$ is positive. But $\lambda > 0$ as it said in the question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a problem at the very beginning: $f$ is not a distribution, as its integral on $(0,+\infty)$ is not $1$, but $\lambda$. So you have to scale $f$ first.

Comment: The preceding seems fixed when you get $\lambda^{2n}$ in the denominator (maybe you forgot the square in your question?). But there is also a sign error near the end: the solution of $\frac{-2n}\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sum_ix_i=0$ is $\hat\lambda=\frac{\sum_ix_i}{2\lambda}$, no minus sign.

Comment: MLE is any point on the possible range where the likelihood is maximized. If it happens to be the global maxima (obtained through differentiation), then it will agree with the MLE. But if the global maxima falls outside the possible range, then you'll need to find the local maxima in the range

Comment: But then again like one comment pointed out, there shouldn't be any minus sign in $\hat{\lambda}$

Answer (score 1):

From the distribution of [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution),

$$f(x) = \frac1{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

Now, let $\theta$ be $\lambda$ and $k$ be $2$, we know that

$$f(x) = \frac1{\Gamma(2)\lambda^2}xe^{-\frac{x}\lambda}=\frac{xe^{-\frac{x}\lambda}}{\lambda^2}$$ is a valid distribution.

From your working, it shows that you are aware that power of $2$ should be there in the denominator.

Now, from $$-\frac{2n}{\lambda}+\frac1{\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$$

We have $$\frac1{\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \frac{2n}{\lambda}$$

Multiply by $\frac{\lambda^2}{2n}$,

$$\lambda = \frac1{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i > 0$$

Note that the second derivative is

$$\frac{2n}{\lambda^2}-\frac2{\lambda^3}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac2{\lambda^2}\left(n-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\lambda} \right)<0$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you´ve omitted the number 2 at the pdf. Beside that it looks fine. You have

> $$ \frac{-2n}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 0$$

So far so good. Next multiplying the equation by $\lambda^2$

$$ -2n\lambda + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 0 \qquad|+2n\lambda $$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 2n\lambda   \qquad|:2n $$

$$\hat \lambda=\frac1{2n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$